# Подскажите как можно отрефакторить код

Tags: php, laravel

Вроде все работает. Подскажите, как можно поправить код, где отрефакторить?

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Dummy;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Database\Seeds\SequenceTrait;
use App\Models\ColdModule\ColdCustomer;
use App\Models\Tag;

class TagSeeder extends Seeder
{
    use SequenceTrait;

    protected $taggable = [];

    /**
     * Prepare all taggable classes
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->taggable = [
            new ColdCustomer,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Auto generated seed file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $table     = new Tag;
        $tableName = $table->getTable();
        \DB::table($tableName)->delete();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            factory(Tag::class)->create($this->getTaggable());
        }
        $this->setSequence($tableName);
    }

    /**
     * Return a randomized Model taggables.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTaggable(): array
    {
        $rand = array_rand($this->taggable);
        $model = $this->taggable[$rand];
        $ids   = $model->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $type  = get_class($model);

        return [
            'taggable_id'   => array_rand($ids),
            'taggable_type' => $type,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы поступил следующим образом:

Создал бы файл `TaggableFactory` в папке `factories` с содержимым для заполнения таблицы

```
$factory->define(Tag::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $taggable = [
        new ColdCustomer,
    ];

    $rand = array_rand($taggable);
    $model = $taggable[$rand];
    $ids   = $model->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $type  = get_class($model);

    return [
        'taggable_id'   => array_rand($ids),
        'taggable_type' => $type,
    ];
});
```

После чего, в `TagSeeder`

```
public function run(): void {
   factory(Tag::class, 50)->create();
}
```

В функции `factory` вторым параметром передается значение сколько вам нужно создать строк в базе.

Если вы запускаете `seeder` с помощью `php artisan db:seed`, то в `DatabaseSeeder` в методе `run` добавить строку `$this->call(TagSeeder::class);`

---

Как видите я убрал очищение таблицы `Tag`, с помощью команды `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, данная команда сделает рестарт всех ваших миграций + заполнит новыми данными, но если вам нужно будет все таки удалять строки из таблицы используйте `Tag::truncate();`